# Packaging chromedriver with selenium script using ocra

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ocra

I made a script using selenium-webdriver to automate some work tasks. I want to distribute this to my co workers so I made it into a .exe using ocra. The problem is that it won't run on someone elses computer because they lack the chromedriver.exe file. Is there a way to include this in the .exe somehow?

Comment: I had the same problem and actually I provide two exes: My application (generated with ocra) and chromedriver.exe. During creation of my exe, I must use my script with Internet Explorer and Firefox to allow the users the choice of there browser. I hopeyou get a better solution :)

Comment: When you provided chromedriver.exe did you need to do anything so your selenium knew where to find it?

Comment: I said in the same directory as the ocra-exe - but to be honest, I'm not sure if anybody ever used chrome.

Comment: @knut I am pretty new at this. Now I am trying to make it work for firefox since there is nothing extra needed for it to work with selenium, but it is still failing on computers other than my own. Do you know why this might be happening?